# Hibernate 3 - safe to reuse IntegerType/StringType etc. objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate3

I have some code/application which uses Hibernate 3.

It does calls like:
`query.setParameter("MRC", getPageName(), new StringType());`
`query.setParameter("MBID", getMBID(), new IntegerType());`

I want to replace these calls with some code like:
`query.setParameter("MRC", getPageName(), STRING_TYPE);`
`query.setParameter("MBID", getMBID(), INTEGER_TYPE);`

so that I don't have to instantiate these objects 
(the 3rd parameters) each time.

Here `STRING_TYPE` and `INTEGER_TYPE` will be static private class variables 
of types `StringType` and `IntegerType` respectively.

I wonder if that's safe to do (e.g. from multi-threading perspective, or purely
from object reuse perspective).

I noticed that in later versions of Hibernate they imposed using 
the 2nd way of coding, but I am not sure if it's safe to follow 
this newer pattern in Hibernate 3 too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use setString(), setInteger(), etc. It would be simpler, cleaner, and safer.

Comment: @JBNizet Because `setInteger` doesn't fit my needs, it does not allow me to pass the `Integer` `null` to the DB function which I am calling. It requires an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StringType has **<edited>no</edited>** member fields and therefore no state itself. In the source code, all operations are either performed directly on the parameters or deal with singleton objects. That means that reusing a singleton instance is just as safe as creating a new instance each time. However, since the singleton instances are also immutable objects (a string constanct, String.class, or a static final int), then both variations should be considered safe.

Here is the source code.

```
package org.hibernate.type;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;

/**
 * <tt>string</tt>: A type that maps an SQL VARCHAR to a Java String.
 * @author Gavin King
 */
public class StringType extends ImmutableType implements DiscriminatorType {

    public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getString(name);
    }

    public Class getReturnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    public void set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws     SQLException {
        st.setString(index, (String) value);
    }

    public int sqlType() {
        return Types.VARCHAR;
    }

    public String getName() { return "string"; }

    public String objectToSQLString(Object value, Dialect dialect) throws Exception {
        return '\'' + (String) value + '\'';
    }

    public Object stringToObject(String xml) throws Exception {
        return xml;
    }

    public String toString(Object value) {
        return (String) value;
    }

    public Object fromStringValue(String xml) {
        return xml;
    }

}
```

Comment: "The StringType has member fields" ... I guess you meant : "The StringType has `no` member fields"? Btw, this code which you showed here... is it from Hibernate v3?

Comment: Oops. Typo. Yes. Edited my answer. The STringType has no member fields. The code here is from hibernate 3. (3.3.2.GA)

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess the same applies to IntegerType too?

Comment: Exactly. IntegerType is also safe to use. Same justification. I looked at the source code for hibernate 3.3.2.GA

Comment: OK... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

StringType has an INSTANCE-Field which contains an instance you can reuse. The Type-Classes map between Java and SQL-Types and have no state, so it's fine to reuse them.

Comment: Can you back it up with some code? [Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/type/StringType.html) dont match [code on github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/StringType.java)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The next version of Hibernate, that you're looking at on Github, is 5.x.x. The documentation you linked to is 3.2. Many years have passed since 3.2, and many changes have been done. It went out in 2006, 13 years ago.

Comment: Ups, the INSTANCE-Field was added later. But one can define a constant and reuse it. Multithreading isn't an issue also, because the class is stateless.

Comment: The constants exist in 3.6. One can only hope that the OP is at least using the latest 3.x version.

Comment: By the way, Hibernate detects Strings and Integers itself, so there is no need to specify the type. Just use the setParameter-Method with two parameters.

Comment: @JBNizet i know that they are different versions. Thats why i asked for code from hibernate3

Comment: Of course the INSTANCE field was added later than in version 3. That's what my question is all about. The first thing I did was to look for this INSTANCE field (because in other projects/apps I use later versions of Hibernate which have that field). But Hibernate 3 does not have that field. And that's what raised my question.